# обрезать часть картинки

Tags: css

Если посмотреть код, смысл в том, чтобы заставить ***3-ю картинку*** быть по высоте как и ***2 первые*** не сжимаясь. А лишнее снизу скрыть. То есть ***3-я картинка*** по высоте выше ***2-х первых***. Нужно скрыть все , что вылазит за рамки.

Прошу помощи.

```css
#myImg,
#myImg2,
#myImg3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover,
#myImg2:hover,
#myImg3:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ф000ff/000000" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img id="myImg2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff0009/000000" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img id="myImg3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000" alt="Snow" style="width:100%; max-width:300px; overflow: hidden">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Завернуть в div с нужными размерами и overflow: hidden